# Raise an error and/or unit test if the Spree Deface Original Changed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, deface

Currently [Spree Deface](https://github.com/spree/deface) will log an error if the original view changes.  For example:

```
Deface: [ERROR] The original source for 'spree/foo' has changed, this override should be reviewed to ensure it's still valid.
```

Does anyone know of way to raise an error if the [original](https://github.com/spree/deface#optional) changed?  A way to unit test that the original is the same as the override?

For example if I have an override that looks like:

```rb
Deface::Override.new(
  virtual_path 'spree/foo',
  name 'foo',
  insert_before: "[data-hook='button']"
  original: 'abcde12345',
  partial: 'spree/foo'
)
```

Is there a raise to an error if `spree/foo` changed?  A way to unit test that `spree/foo` has not changed?

Thanks.